# JMeter Cookiemanager behaves differently between Windows and Linux

Tags: ubuntu, cookies, jmeter, load-testing

I have created a testplan in JMeter 3.3 that is performing a series of GET and POST requests to log into our application and logout again. In order to capture and use apply cookies to the POST requests, the testplan is using the JMeter Cookie Manager with cookie policy 'standard-strict', which is working perfectly fine on my local Windows pc.
The plan is to run the test on an Ubuntu AWS instance in non-GUI mode with (currently) JMeter 3.0 using command

```
jmeter -n -t ./Login_nogui.jmx -Ljmeter.protocol.http.control.DNSCacheManager=DEBUG -l ./JMeter_LoginResults.csv -Djmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
```

Unfortunately, all requests keep failing there with following error:

```
Non HTTP response code: java.lang.NullPointerException,Non HTTP response message: null
```

I believe I have narrowed the source of the problem down to the JMeter Cookie Manager and tried other cookie policies, but they either lead to the same result, or the requests are successful, but the login fails, e.g. using cookie policy 'default'.
Did I miss anything or is there a way to make the cookie manager work on Ubuntu same way as on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't expect different version of JMeter to execute the same, specifically 
[Cookie implementation changed](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) from JMeter 3.0 to 3.3 so I suggest you use JMeter 3.3 version in linux

From changes:

> In CookieManager, DEFAULT_POLICY and DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATION constants are now private.
>   If you're using ignorecookies with HC3CookieHandler (< JMeter 3.1) configuration will be reset, ensure you put it back.

Comment: Thanks, upgrading to JMeter 3.3 did indeed solve the issue.